# How to validate a complete form with RSpec and Capybara?

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

I'm writing a request test with RSpec and Capybara. I have a hash that maps form field names to expected values.

How can I check easily that each form field has the expected value?

So far, I'm doing this, but it's complex and unmaintainable. I'm also considering only two kind of input controls in this case (select boxes and the rest):

```
expected_data = { 
  "address" => "Fake st 123",
  "city" => "Somewhere",
  "email" => "whoknows@example.com",
  "gender" => "Male",
  "state" => "FL",
}

select_boxes = ["gender", "state"]
# check for the select boxes
expected_data.select {|k,v| select_boxes.include?(k)}.each do |name, expected_value|
  page.has_select?(name, :selected_value => expected_value).should == true
end 
# check for the input fields
expected_data.reject {|k,v| select_boxes.include?(k)}.values.each do |expected_value|
  page.should have_css("input[value=\"#{expected_value}\"]")
end
```

Is there a gem or something to do this in one line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find the following far more maintainable:

```
describe "form" do
  subject {page}

  before { visit "/path/to/form" }

  it { should have_field("address", :with => "Fake st 123") }
  it { should have_select("gender", :selected => "Male") }
  # And so on ...
end
```

Comment: Seems nice! Let me check this up

Comment: It works! And I can also use `:selected_value`. Thanks for your help!